# Feathers client can't see api data

Tags: feathersjs

using latest fethersjs and mongodb.

I've made a small feathersjs app using mongoose. It worked fine on my laptop. I deployed it on ubuntu 16.04 using PM2.

Using feathers client, I cannot retrieve any data from DB but there is actually 30744500 documents in it.

Using API I find records (/items):

```
{"total":30744500,"limit":100,"skip":0,"data": ...data..}
```

Here is my /public app.js summary:

```
// Establish a Socket.io connection
const socket = io();
// Initialize our Feathers client application through Socket.io
// with hooks and authentication.
const client = feathers();

client.configure(feathers.socketio(socket));
// Use localStorage to store our login token
client.configure(feathers.authentication({
  storage: window.localStorage
}));
query_obj = getQueryObj();
const events = await client.service('events').find(query_obj);
max_ = events.total;
console.log('total:'+max_);
events.data.forEach(addEvent);
```

... where query_obj is equal to :

> {"query":{"$sort":{"timestamp":-1},"$limit":100,"$skip":0}}

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

EDIT :

But now I'm having a Timeout error when executing a find command. Chrome's console telles me this:

```
 app.js:181 {"query":{"$sort":{"timestamp":-1},"$limit":100,"$skip":0}}
index.js:135 Uncaught (in promise) Timeout {type: "FeathersError", name: "Timeout", message: "Timeout of 5000ms exceeded calling find on events", code: 408, className: "timeout", …}className: "timeout"code: 408data: method: "find"path: "events"timeout: 5000__proto__: constructor: ƒ Object()hasOwnProperty: ƒ hasOwnProperty()isPrototypeOf: ƒ isPrototypeOf()propertyIsEnumerable: ƒ propertyIsEnumerable()toLocaleString: ƒ toLocaleString()toString: ƒ toString()valueOf: ƒ valueOf()__defineGetter__: ƒ __defineGetter__()__defineSetter__: ƒ __defineSetter__()__lookupGetter__: ƒ __lookupGetter__()__lookupSetter__: ƒ __lookupSetter__()get __proto__: ƒ __proto__()set __proto__: ƒ __proto__()errors: __proto__: Objectmessage: "Timeout of 5000ms exceeded calling find on events"name: "Timeout"type: "FeathersError"stack: "Timeout: Timeout of 5000ms exceeded calling find on events↵    at new Timeout (https://unpkg.com/@feathersjs/client@3.4.4/dist/feathers.js:1468:17)↵    at https://unpkg.com/@feathersjs/client@3.4.4/dist/feathers.js:2903:23"__proto__: FeathersErrorconstructor: ƒ Timeout(message, data)arguments: (...)caller: (...)length: 2name: "Timeout"prototype: FeathersErrorconstructor: ƒ Timeout(message, data)__proto__: Error__proto__: ƒ ()[[FunctionLocation]]: index.js:134[[Scopes]]: Scopes[3]__proto__: Errorconstructor: ƒ FeathersError(msg, name, code, className, data)toJSON: ƒ value()__proto__: Object
showLogViewer @ app.js:288
async function (async)
showLogViewer @ app.js:245
login @ app.js:318
async function (async)
login @ app.js:303
(anonymous) @ app.js:383
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: This is what is strange, it simply do not throw any (or any that I can find)... just an empty record set. Is the database too big?

Comment: @Daff ok I finally got It! I just used the wrong service (Shoot me in th head!).

Comment: @Daff But now I'm experiencing a timeout (see my post edit) when clients launches find querry. Still the api works... Any clue? Thanks...

Comment: Did you create an index on `timestamp`?

Comment: Now I did and it works! Thanks a lot @Daff